# Show image details of selected image

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-router, react-state

I'm using an API that returns random images each time. The app currently displayed 6 random images from the API, however I'm now trying to achieve a page that displays the image data, such as the date, description etc. How would I go about this as every time I make a request on the details page, new data is received back.

The page that shows the images and title:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const FeaturedProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const fetchProducts = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod/?api_key=xxxxxxxxx&count=6&thumbs=True/"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.title}>
          <p>{product.title}</p>
          <img src={product.url} />
          <Link to={`/product/${product.title}`}>View</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FeaturedProducts;
```

The details page that seems to always bring back new data (not saving the old state):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Product = ({ match }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();
  }, []);

  const fetchProduct = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod/?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&count=6&thumbs=True/?title=${match.params.title}`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.title}>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Back</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

App.js file for routing:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

import FeaturedProducts from "./FeaturedProducts";
import Product from "./Product";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={FeaturedProducts} />
          <Route exact path="/product/:title" component={Product} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: From the API documentation there seems to be no way to query the results based on the title of the image. As you are already saving the image meta in products state inside FeaturedProducts component, instead of making an Ajax call again in the Products component, you can pass the required values as props from FeaturedProducts component to the Product component and then use them to display the meta inside the Products component.

Comment: @VineetDesai I'm not sure how you'd go about passing the values as props to the product component. Any idea how or any documents that will guide me? Thanks

Comment: in the FeaturedProducts component use `<Link to={{pathname: '/product/${product.title}', productProps: {title: product.title, explanation: product.explanation}}}>View</Link>`. In the Product component, access the props using `props.location.productProps`

Comment: @VineetDesai Seem to getting an error with this: const Product = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const product = props.location.productProps;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{product.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: What is the error? can you edit your post with the updates?

Comment: I've added this to Product page however when I click on the link, the title isn't being rendered. Have I got the syntax correct? `const Product = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const productTitle = props.location.productProps;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{productTitle}</p>
    </div>
  );
};`

Comment: Try `location.productProps` instead of `props.location.productProps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments, pass the details from `FeaturedProducts` to `Product` component, instead of making an API call in the `Product` component

In the `FeaturedProducts` component

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/product/${product.title}', productProps: {title: product.title, explanation: product.explanation}}}>View</Link>
```

In the `Product` component, read the properties using `useLocation` hook

```
const location = useLocation();
const title = location.productProps.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page that shows images and titles, the Link should be like this:

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: `/product/${product.title}`,
    state: { mainProducts: products }
  }}
```

And from details page

```
import {
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

let location = useLocation();

let product = location.state.mainProducts;
```

//this will get the desired images